# Not able to integrate versionone with bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla, versionone

I am facing error during bugzilla integration with versionone.

C:\Apache24\htdocs\bugzilla-4.0.15\bugzilla\extensions>perl TestV1Service.pl http ://bugmachine/bugzilla-4.0.15/bugzilla/index.cgi username@gmail.com secret

Connect to Bugzilla instance located at http: //bugmachine/bugzilla-4.0.15/bugzilla/index.cgi
Using Credentials username@gmail.com/secret
Can't call method "paramsall" on an undefined value at TestV1Service.pl line 77.

C:\Apache24\htdocs\bugzilla-4.0.15\bugzilla\extensions>

Process of integration:

1. Downloaded V1BugzillaIntegration.8.3
2. renamed  V1BugzillaIntegration.8.3\BugzillaScripts\4.0.x\Bugzilla\extensions\V1Integration folder to
   to V1
3. Copied V1 to C:\Apache24\htdocs\bugzilla-4.0.15\bugzilla\extensions

System :

- bugzilla version 4.0.15
- perl 5.16.1
- OS windows7
- SOAP-Lite
- Test-Taint and
- JSON-RPC are installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not hitting the right xmlRpc endpoint.  The goal of running TestV1Service.pl is to test your XMLRpc Web services.

You have

`http: //bugmachine/bugzilla-4.0.15/bugzilla/index.cgi` Likely your main BZ page.

Try and hit

`http: //bugmachine/bugzilla-4.0.15/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi` instead.

You could also get the latest [VerisionOne/Bugzilla integration](http://v1appcatalog.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html#/Details/VersionOne.Integration.Bugzilla)  which is 8.4.2.  This works with up to BZ 4.4.